# JSON file processing error: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1] when use file in UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, json, encoding, utf-8, apache-commons-io

I have a valid JSON-file. I want to read it into a memory as `JSONArray` object.

In order to do that I use the following code (powered by Apache Commons IO 2.5):

```java
String jsonTxt = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(file.json), "UTF-8");
JSONArray itemsArr = new JSONArray(jsonTxt);
```

But I get the error:

```java
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:433)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:106)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:145)
    at myOrg.infomedia.dba.NewsSourcesData.loadNewsSourcesData(NewsSourcesData.java:39)
    at myOrg.infomedia.main.Main.main(Main.java:65)
```

After multiple checks, I found out that the root of the problem is the file encoding. If I provide a file in `UTF-8`, it throws exception, but if I convert the file to `ANSI` everything is working correctly.

I'm using `org.json` version *json-20160212.jar*.

How can I get `JSONArray` from my JSON-file in `UTF-8` encoding?

Comment: if you log `jsonTxt` is it valid JSON?

Comment: @Yazan, yes.At least `IDEA 2016.1` and `jsonlint.com` claim this.

Comment: thats weird!  another note is `character 2 line 1` so what's the 1st character? is it some kind of invalid character (invisible maybe?), and another question, by `if I convert the file to ASCII` you mean convert the file encoding (save as) or just use other encoding name in your `readFileToString()` ?

Comment: I think you have a file encode in UTF-8 with BOM https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark  try to convert file using Notepad++ or something similiar to UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: @Yazan, under `convert the file to ASCII` I mean `Save as` in notepad. BTW, of course, it's `ANSI` and not `ASCII`.

Comment: @Ilya, bingo! The problem was with `BOM`. Please, arrange your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a file encode in [UTF-8 with BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) try to convert file using Notepad++ or something similiar to UTF-8 without BOM